# Loading CSV to Odoo

Tags: csv, odoo, odoo-12

I would like to know if it is possible to directly import CSV file to Odoo using External API.

I have searched a bit and did not find a proper answer. Any link guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `base_import` module, you will need to properly configure your `POST` data if you want to use `set_file` controller, or use your own controller. For example, `set_file` controller function expects file body in `file` attribute, an `import_id` attribute (Integer value). Checkout the function definition:

```
class ImportController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/base_import/set_file', methods=['POST'])
    def set_file(self, file, import_id, jsonp='callback'):
        import_id = int(import_id)

        written = request.env['base_import.import'].browse(import_id).write({
            'file': file.read(),
            'file_name': file.filename,
            'file_type': file.content_type,
        })

        return 'window.top.%s(%s)' % (misc.html_escape(jsonp), json.dumps({'result': written}))
```

Comment: I am using external API
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html